# React Router Link to the same URL but send different state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need some help how to open the same url with `react-router` `Link` but sending different state.

```
<Link 
  to={items.vehicleModelId === 2
    ? '/ecgo-3'
    : items.vehicleModelId === 3 && '/ecgo-5'
  }
  state={{ id: items.id }}
>
  {items.name}
</Link>
```

For example I have 2 links to `"/ecgo-5"` but I need to send different state for each one of them. When I am already on `"/ecgo-5"` path and then I click the the another link to send the different state, the page wont refresh with the new state.

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two separate links that pass *different* route state, or a single link that conditionally passes *different* route states, then the routed component that receives the state should handle `location.state` updates during the life of the component, e.g. while it is mounted. Use the `useEffect` hook to "listen" to and handle any changes on the `location.state` value.

Example:

```
<Link 
  to="/ecgo-5"
  state={{ id: /* value A */ }}
>
  {items.name}
</Link>
```

```
<Link 
  to="/ecgo-5"
  state={{ id: /* value B */ }}
>
  {items.name}
</Link>
```

```
const Ecgo5 = () => {
  const { state } = useLocation();
  const { id } = state || {};

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // id value updated, value A or B, or ...?
    // ... logic ...
  }, [id]);

  ...
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the to prop of the Link component dynamically based on the condition you mentioned. However, the state object should be provided as a prop directly to the Link component, not as part of the to prop. Here's an example:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

<Link
  to={{
    pathname: items.vehicleModelId === 2 ? '/ecgo-3' : '/ecgo-5',
    state: { id: items.id }
  }}
>
  {items.name}
</Link>
```

In this example, the to prop is an object that consists of the pathname and state properties. The pathname is determined based on the condition, and the state object contains the desired state to be passed to the target URL.

When you click on the link, React Router will handle the navigation and update the URL without causing a full page refresh. The new component rendered for the target URL can access the state using the location.state property.

Make sure you have set up the necessary route configurations in your React Router setup to handle the /ecgo-3 and /ecgo-5 URLs and retrieve the state using the location.state object in the destination component.